# How can I change my jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a slide like the one on this link. I would like to change the function from sliding to dropping. Any insights?

http://unlimited.ndot.in/

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the code

`$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});`

in the slider plugin documentation.

Good luck.